# Relation between the Complex Number System and Vector Spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, complex-numbers, soft-question, vectors

Given that any Complex Number $z$ can be represented as a Vector in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and since a Vector is nothing more than an element of a Vector Space (in its most general form), does that not imply that the set of Complex Numbers ($\mathbb{C}$) is a two-dimensional Vector Space in $\mathbb{R^2}$ over the field of Real Numbers itself?

Comment: Yes, it does. Of course, something must be proved here: that the operations on $\;\Bbb C\;$ make it a linear space over $\;\Bbb R\;$ , but this is almost trivial.

Comment: It is usually less interersting to consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ than it is to consider $\mathbb{C}$ as a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: In fact the Cauchy-Riemann equations give the relation between 1) complex differentiability of a function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as a function on a one-dimensional complex vector space, and 2) real differentiability of $f$ regarded as a function on $\mathbb{C}$ as a two-dimensional real vector space,